# Form authentication slidingExpiration does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, form-authentication, slidingexpiration

I have below code

```
int intTimeout = (FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Hours * 60) +
  FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes;
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Utility.userCookie, DateTime.Now, 
  DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intTimeout), true, cookieValue);

string strEncryptedTicket = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
var authCookie = new HttpCookie(Utility.userCookie, strEncryptedTicket);
authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
//FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("", false);
authCookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;
//authCookie.Secure = true;

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[Utility.userCookie].Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[Utility.userCookie].Value = authCookie.Value;
```

Below *web.config*

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="2" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

I keep hitting page link, **still it expires in 2 minutes**.

Comment: Please provide more details: 1) version of web server you're hosting this, 2) do you have any changes around FormAuthenticationModule in your web.config 3) What is the value of Utility.userCookie ?

Comment: can you provide your web.config file??

Comment: Where are you resissuing the `authCookie` as part of the response?  It appears you are creating one then never sending back to the user.  Next....are you sure you are not using the Identity framework? Any project created in the past few years would not be using forms authentication by default and thus any settings you place there would not be respected by the Identity framework.

Comment: I have given web.config details whatever there related to form authentication

Comment: what is your asp.net version?

Comment: mvc5 visual studo 15

Answer (score 3):

Please pay attention to the structure of **custom forms–based authentication** in *web.config*:

```
<forms 
   name="name" 
   loginUrl="URL" 
   defaultUrl="URL"
   protection="[All|None|Encryption|Validation]"
   timeout="[MM]"
   path="path"
   requireSSL="[true|false]"
   slidingExpiration="[true|false]">
   enableCrossAppRedirects="[true|false]"
   cookieless="[UseUri|UseCookies|AutoDetect|UseDeviceProfile]" 
   domain="domain name"
   ticketCompatibilityMode="[Framework20|Framework40]">
   <credentials>...</credentials>
</forms>
```

As you see, `timeout` property works based on minutes where you set it 2 (e.g. 2 minutes).

Generally, if you enable `slidingExpiration` in *web.config*. **You have no need to regenerate a new cookie manually**. For your scenario, I suggest you to use a trace tool e.g. Fiddler. When you refresh the page, you can check from Fiddler that whether the cookie expired time is reset.

I found a good example in [Weird Timeouts With Custom ASPNETFormsAuthentication](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WeirdTimeoutsWithCustomASPNETFormsAuthentication.aspx) which can do some clearance for you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is related to lack of static `machineKey` section in the web.config file. when you call `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt` or `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt`, the methods use the machineKey values which is provided in the web.config file to perform the operation. if you do not provide strict values for machineKey, a new unique `validationKey` and `decryptionKey` would generate at the start point of the web application. sometimes depend on the server settings(for example small Idle-Time values for application pool settings), application is terminated before the expiration time of the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`. in this case because of the new `machineKey` values the Decrypt method can't validate the Ticket. I just recommend you to set a static machineKey.

see the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my application, I define `cookieAuthenticationOptions` in `Startup.cs` like this and it works fine

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                CookieName = "App.Authentication",
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            });
```

Do you define those options ?

Why you don't use the `SignIn` method of `AuthenticationManager` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this line from your code and try again:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[Utility.userCookie].Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
```

Answer (score 1):

In web.config file either remove `<clear/>` element or add following after `<clear/>` element if not present.

```
<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
```